# Is memory barrier meaningful only in SMP?

Tags: concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

I understand why memory barriers are needed, but I don't get it in the case of Uniprocessor.

Do I have to deal with barriers even when I use UP? Every document explains them with SMP but not UP.

In the following code, is there any possibility that `r2 == 0` in point a?

```
// the location 0xdeadbeef has a zero initial value
ldr r0, =0xdeadbeef
ldr r1, =0xdeadbeef
ldr r2, =1
str r2, [r0]
ldr r2, [r1]
// point a
```

Comment: Could be relevant on superscalar out-of-order single processors. It really should be specified by the processor's memory model and instruction set. (the evil is in the details).

Comment: @Basile: I don't think so - the iron rule is execution of a single thread on a single processor always has effect following cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are memory barriers and compiler barriers.

Memory barriers are not required on a single processor (I'm not sure if hyperthreading counts as multiple processors) but compiler barriers are - the compiler could re-order the code in different threads such that you fail.

Answer (score 0):

Memory barriers must be used only for "global variables". Because local (in stack) and registers are automatically saved while threads switched.

May be universality is better than assumption that you always deal with UP